# Different shipping method for different customer group in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to show free shipping for LOGGED IN user and flat rate shipping for not logged in user.

I have set up two rules to achieve this from magento admin --> Promotion --> Shopping cart price rule. But it is not working. Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: What did you try? Error? Code? we are not mind readers

Comment: I have enabled free shipping and flat rate shipping methods. I want to show free shipping for logged in user and flat rate for guest (Not logged in user). Hope it helps to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. But there is an extension available which can do this:

http://amasty.com/shipping-payment-by-customer-group.html

Not free, but it worked perfectly for me.